# How to insert a hyperlink in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, uitextview

I want to insert a hyperlink as we have in uiwebview. As the link displayed as Read More and when user click on it then it must be redirected to a URL in iPhone browser (i.e safari).

Please don't suggest me using UIwebview in place of it. And don't suggest me

> textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

Because in second way the url displayed to the user, which I don't want.

Give me any other suggestions to achieve this or any sample code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it have to be a textView? I did some similar adding a button with the text, background invisible and add the action to call safari on click, like this:

```
    UIButton *hiperlinkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [hiperlinkButton setTitle:@"your text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [hiperlinkButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:33.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [hiperlinkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(yourposition and size)];
    [hiperlinkButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    [hiperlinkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callSafari:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [contactsView insertSubview:hyperlinkButton aboveSubview:contactsView];
```

Comment: Umm.. what is contactOrkut? shouldn't it be hiperlinkbutton? why is this even marked as correct?